# sql column collation does not replicate through to subscribers

Tags: sql, sql-server, replication, collation

I have Transactional Replication setup in a 2012 SQL Environment.

When I change a column's collation on the published DB from `Latin1_General_CI_AS` to `SQL_Latin1_General_Cp1_CI_AS` it replicates through to the subscribers no problem. Without Re Initialize or generating a new snapshot.

BUT When I do it the other way around ie. From `SQL_Latin1_General_Cp1_CI_AS` to `Latin1_General_CI_AS`, it does not replicate. It only changes after Re Initialize with new snapshot.

Can anyone please explain this.

PS. There's no errors or logs with an indication of why it does not replicate through.